# Why is my conditional not working in my object method?

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, methods, conditional-statements

Could someone help explain why the arguments passed to my displayHitMiss method are not meeting the criteria for a "hit". They are all skipping to "miss" even when they match with a location. I have tried swapping the setAttributes around, which makes it display only "hits", so the problem has to be with my conditional, right?

Cheers,

Rob.

```
var location1 = "00";
var location2 = "34";
var location3 = "48";

var view = {
    //Message area takes a string and displays it
    displayMessage: function(msg) {
        var messageArea = document.getElementById("messageArea");
        messageArea.innerHTML = msg;
    },
    //Board displays hit
    displayHitMiss: function (location) {
        var cell = document.getElementById(location);
        if (cell == location1 || cell == location2 || cell == location3) {
            cell.setAttribute("class", "hit");
        } else {
            cell.setAttribute("class", "miss");
        }
    }
};


view.displayMessage("Is this thing on?");
view.displayHitMiss("00");
view.displayHitMiss("46");
view.displayHitMiss("34");
view.displayHitMiss("03");
```

Comment: cell is an object that is an element with the name passed as your parameter, so it can never be equal.  You want to check cell's attribute that holds that value, not the object cell.

Comment: Ah, a simple fix.
I just removed 'cell' from the comparison and replaced it with the parameters 'location' variable.

Top man.